# How much does it take to discharge a capacitor in the vacuum?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, discharge, vacuum

We have charged a capacitor with a specified voltage. Between the capacitor's plate, we have vacuum. So how does this capacitor can be discharged if we place this capacitor in the vacuum? As you can see, we do not have any discharging path neither between capacitor's plate nor between capacitor's lead. How much does it take to discharge this capacitor?

Pay attention that this is a fully theoretical question. we do not have even a single atom between two plates.

Comment: We need a lot more info to answer your question. What's the capacitance? What voltage do you charge the capacitor up to? How are the plates mounted? What material is the mounting mechanism made out of? Did you clean and degrease all of the interior and exterior surfaces of the capacitor? How are you measuring the voltage? Are you measuring the voltage continuously or not? What's the input impedance of the measuring setup? Could you show us a picture of the capacitor? And are you trying to discharge the cap, or wondering how it's being discharged when you'd expect it not to discharge?

Comment: @JonathanS. mentions some possible discharge mechanisms. In addition, ionizing radiation can provide a discharge mechanism (including natural radioactivity). Usually slow, and dangerous to humans, since radiation may have to penetrate the vacuum vessel unless it is installed inside.

Comment: Why do you need to discharge it? Why not leave it charged?

Comment: Thank you guys, especially @JonathanS.,
actually I just wanted to use fundamental formula of physics to solve this issue. For example, imagine that we have just two metal plates in parallel with a large work function. we do not want to use high voltage in order to avoid field electric emission. Well I aimed to use 4*R*C formula to find this value, not measuring the voltage.

Comment: If this is a purely theoretical question and you start considering work functions and the like, probably the best place to ask this is on physics.SE. We deal with idealized capacitors, of course, but in the context of electronics, so the assumptions we engineers make are usually quite different than those made by physicists. In other words, we consider a capacitor as a component (albeit idealized at times) and not something whose internals are particularly interesting. Except if some EE is into capacitors design, but in that case there are no idealizations, but just hard technology stuff.

Comment: @JonathanS. Agree in full. Just a note: the OP states a "pure theoretical question" where he wants to assume absolutely no atom the plates. This is so idealized even in hard vacuum, that has little do do with engineering and more to do with mathematical physics. And since it is so theoretical, it misses lots of assumptions (e.g. does the crystalline structure of the plates matters or are they considered "simple" ideal conductor pieces, a la physics 101 exercises).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We have charged a capacitor with a specified voltage. Between the capacitor's plate, we have vacuum. So how does this capacitor can be discharged if we place this capacitor in the vacuum?

It doesn't discharge. It just sits there, at the same voltage.

> As you can see, we do not have any discharging path neither between capacitor's plate nor between capacitor's lead.

That's why it doesn't discharge.

> How much does it take to discharge this capacitor?

It takes a conducting path, or some other way, of moving charge from one plate to the other.

An example of a 'conducting path' would be a wire or resistor, connected between the plates.

An example of 'some other way' would be UV illumination. This would knock electrons off the plates by photo-emission, which could then drift between the plates in the appropriate direction to discharge the capacitor. This method of discharging a capacitor was used on the Gravity Probe B mission, where it was vital to have near zero voltage between a spinning sphere and its enclosure. The sphere gradually picked up charge during the mission due to cosmic rays, and UV illumination was used periodically to discharge it.

Another example of 'some other way' would be a small piece of conductor brought into contact alternately with each plate. This can be seen in the [Oxford Electric Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_Electric_Bell) where the clapper carries a small current between the two bells.

Bear in mind that the voltage on a high quality vacuum capacitor will jump around randomly by small increments, as cosmic rays dump charge on either plate. This effect was noted by Bob Pease, in [one of his articles](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/test-measurement/article/21766108/whats-all-this-femtoampere-stuff-anyhow) (not pay-walled, but free-limited) describing how to measure currents at the fA (femtoamp) level. [Here's a youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4G3YPlO6Wg) of Bob in action, 27:15 is where he's talking about the cosmic rays. Of course in a vacuum, there's no air to ionise, so the effect will be statistically smaller, as it's lacking the ionisation multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

Even with a vacuum some electrons will jump off one plate and join the other plate (discharge) due to outside excitation of electrons.  Conditions would have to be perfect, absolutely no outside disturbance in order for a capacitor to hold its charge forever.

Comment: it would be great if you add a link to support your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If there is nothing in between the plates then the voltage would stay the same forever. If you add any material to the plate such as air it adds resistance because every material has some kind of conductivity (there are no perfect super insulators) the leakage current would slowly drain the voltage between the plates.

Answer (score 0):

If the potential energy stored in the capacitor is greater than the work function of the metallic plates electrons will just leave the negative electrically metal and jump to the positive  electrically metal.This is not a continuous current but rather a discharge.The electric potential energy between the plates will be decreased as 1 side becomes less negatively charged and the other side becomes less positively charged.When the electric potential energy stored in the capacitor becomes less than the work function of the material of the metallic plates this proccess will be stopped and the discharge current will become 0.